# How to calculate the coefficient of kinetic friction of sandpaper by itself

Tags: experimental-physics, friction

I'm not sure if this makes any sense, but could I calculate the kinetic coefficient of friction between sandpaper and sandpaper experimentally, then divide it by 2 for the coefficient of friction of sandpaper and a point mass? Or should I keep it as the kinetic friction between sandpaper and sandpaper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the latter. These kinetic friction coefficients are

- [experimentally found. I don’t know of any formalism to find them mathematically from first principles.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/683873/relation-of-static-and-kinetic-coefficients-of-friction)
- are defined **between** the two material's surfaces

That is, there is no kinetic friction coefficient of sandpaper. There is however, one between sandpaper and sandpaper, one between sandpaper and concrete, one between car wheel material (rubber) and the asphalt. A point particle has no surface so it doesn't make sense to talk about the friction coefficients of it with other surfaces.

These statements are also true for static friction.